# Conversion of windows command output in linux environment in perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am facing one problem. I am writing a Perl program on Linux, where I am executing a windows command on a remote windows machine and capturing output in Perl variable. But there are some unknown characters between every 2 characters.
What introduces this character? PLease help.

Comment: You should include some output here that includes the unknown characters.

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge , Sorry for that. But I could not figure out the way to provide the output. AS part of debugging I subsitituted all non-word chars(\W) to some other character like "!", so I got to know that after every readable character it prints out "!". Regex for substitution: s/\W+/!/g

Answer (score 4):

Windows uses UTF-16LE to encode Unicode strings. You will need to use the [`Encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) module to decode them

It's difficult to know what to advise with so little information, but in general you can write

```
use Encode qw/ decode :fallbacks /;

my $text = decode('UTF-16', $windows_bytes, FB_CROAK);
```

As far as I know, Windows always uses a *Byte Order Mark* (BOM) so I've specified just `UTF-16`. If there were no BOM I would need to specify the byte ordering myself with `UTF-16LE`

The third parameter to `decode` defines the behaviour if the data is an invalid example of the specified encoding. It is safest to *croak* in this case

Or if you're opening a UTF-16-encoded file, you should open with `:encoding(UTF-16)` and `:crlf`, like this

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-16):crlf', $filename;
```

Comment: Would you provide a brief example so that readers (myself included) get to view a minimal snip here, and can then follow through to the docs if desired?

Comment: @stevieb: I was hoping the OP woiuld come up with some more specific information, but I've written something very general

Comment: I figured @Borodin, and I understand. Thank you for updating with some examples regardless of the OPs lack of information. ++